# How can I populate my picker without using a collection list?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been trying to populate my picker but I don't know how. I have looked at some tutorial online but they are kind of confusing and they all create a list of the items which I haven't done.
`New Game Class

```
namespace FYP.ViewModels
{
    public class NewGames
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string GameTitle { get; set; }
        public double Rating { get; set; }
        public string ImageSource { set; get; }
    }
}
```

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;

namespace FYP.ViewModels
{

    public class NewReleasesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private ObservableCollection<NewGames> NewGames;

        public ObservableCollection<NewGames> Games
        {
            get { return NewGames; }
            set { NewGames = value;

                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Games"));
            }
        }

        public NewReleasesViewModel() 
        {
            Games = new ObservableCollection<NewGames>();
            AddData();
        }
        private void AddData()
        {
            Games.Add(new NewGames
            {
                Id = 0,
                GameTitle = "The Elder Scrolls Online",
                Rating = 4.9,
                ImageSource= "https://assets-prd.ignimgs.com/2022/01/05/elderscrollsonline-                             1641413357689.jpg"
            });
            Games.Add(new NewGames
            {
                Id = 1,
                GameTitle = "World Of Warcraft",
                Rating = 4.9,
                ImageSource = "https://assets-prd.ignimgs.com/2021/12/10/wow-1639126324635.jpg"
            });
            Games.Add(new NewGames
            {
                Id = 2,
                GameTitle = "Star Wars: The Old Republic",
                Rating = 4.9,
                ImageSource = "https://assets-prd.ignimgs.com/2022/01/27/swotor-sq1-1643302998212.jpg"
            });


        }
    }
}
```

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
      <Label Text="Select Game" TextColor="Black" FontSize="24" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="15" />
      <Picker>
      </Picker>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I'm trying to do something like this where the user picks a title and then something else loads on the screen
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nMuR.png)

Comment: first, please format your code so it's readable.  Second - you haven't posted any UI code so it's difficult to know what you want to populate.  Do you mean an actual Picker control?  Or something else like a ListView or CollectionView?  The screenshot you posted doesn't illustrate any those options.

Comment: I did format the code but it ended up looking like that let me try and edit it.

Comment: What I'm trying to populate is the picker control and after an item is selected, a box will be added below the picker so the user can write something in it. I am a little bit stupid so hopefully you understand what I'm trying to do. I also fixed the formating

Comment: where exactly are you stuck?  You really just need to assign the Picker's `ItemsSource`.  Have you looked at the docs and samples for Picker?

Comment: How do I assign it? I'm just really confused by the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to assign an `ItemSource`

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Games}" ... />
```

and you need to tell it which property to display

```
ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding GameTitle}" ...
```

Comment: Like this?<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Games}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding GameTitle}"/> I tried it but when I run it there is nothing in the picker

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing the binding context

```
 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:NewReleasesViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Select Game" TextColor="Black" FontSize="24" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="15" />
        <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Games}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding GameTitle}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```